# Finding current through a capacitor in a series AC circuit

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, ac

We are tasked to find the current through a capacitor and the voltage of the capacitor in this circuit **without** using any complex impedances.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVhzsh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

the current equation of the capacitor is Ic(t)=C1d/dt(V(t)) so in this circuit we get the following equation of Ic(t) = 0.5d/dt(2sin(50πt)-Ic(t)*100) but i get an exponential solution which shouldnt be the case.Where am I wrong?

Comment: Do you understand differential equations and how to solve them?

Comment: Jun, It's a sine, cosine, and exponential solution set. The exponential part will dampen out in time so that it's constant is just 1. In this case, because the filter is such a strong low-pass and your frequency is so high by comparison, the exponential part will dampen out before you can see it happen. So it will devolve into a sine/cosine thing right away. Show your work.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set up the problem correctly. Ic(t) is proportional to the derivative of Vc(t) -- the voltage across the capacitor. V(t) -- the driving voltage -- equals Vc(t) + Vr(t) where Vr(t) is the voltage across the resistor.

So to come up with the right differential equation you need to:

1. put in the right proportionality constant in the relation Ic(t) = (some constant)*dVc(t)/dt
2. relate Vr(t) to Ic(t)
3. Use the relationship V(t) = Vc(t) + Vr(t)

Comment: yeah sorry i forgot to put C1 in the equation.